# Generating a tile cache based on external SLD

Tags: geoserver, tilecache, geowebcache

I have a web service that generates an SLD for a layer that varies based on an attribute of the underlying data.  These SLDs don't change, it is just that there are several of them per layer.  I would like a tile cache of at least the first few levels of the pyramid, but GeoWebCache seems to only support this for different styles.  Is there a way to build these caches and have them use the SLD parameter to separate the responses?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to manage this with parameter filters pretty much the same way as with the `STYLE` parameter.  Add a `StringParameterFilter` for the `SLD` parameter, give it the URLs for the external styles, and away you go.